How to find stabilizer generators of a subsystem from a known set of generators?
$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
I am working on a problem and would appreciate some help. I'm working with a multi-qubit state defined by a set of stabilizer generators, ie $\ket{\psi} \in H$ that is the simultaneous $+1$ eigenstate of all of the generators. In QM, we have the idea of a reduced density matrix where we can "forget" some information about the system and obtain the state for just a particular subsystem of $H$.
I am wondering if it is possible to, from a known set of stabilizer generators defining uniquely a quantum state (so $N$ generators for an $N$ qubit state) obtain the stabilizer generators for the state of a subsystem in a similar manner to the reduced density matrix? I doubt this is possible or "nice" in general but in my case $\ket{\psi}$ is pure, and the "reduced" state is not entangled with the rest of the system and is also pure
Specifically I have for the stabilizers
\begin{equation}
S = \{ X_2, Z_1 X_2 Z_3, X_4, Z_3 X_4 Z_5, X_6, Z_5 X_6 Z_7, Y_1 X_3 X_5 Y_7\}
\end{equation}
where $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are the Pauli matricies and $O_i$ is an operator acting on the $i^\text{th}$ qubit. So for example $X_2 = I \otimes X \otimes I \otimes I ...$ and $Z_1 X_2 Z_3 = Z \otimes X \otimes Z \otimes I \otimes ...$
I want to find the reduced state of all the qubits on the odd-numbered sites (they are not entangled with the rest of the system). So, naively we might just "ignore" all of the terms that don't act on these and write $S = \{Z_1 Z_3, Z_3 Z_5, Z_5 Z_7, Y_1 X_3 X_5 Y_7\}$, and, relabelling the indicies and redefining the operators to act in this smaller Hilbert space,
\begin{equation}
S = \{Z_1 Z_2, Z_2 Z_3, Z_3 Z_4, Y_1 X_2 X_3 Y_4\}
\end{equation}
This kind of random guesswork surprisingly gives the correct answer. Again since the states are all pure and there is no entanglement whatsoever between the this subsystem and the subsystem we are "forgetting" it is almost not surprising.
I would really appreciate if someone with more theoretical knowledge on stabilizers could explain if there really exists a procedure like this with stabilizers? Is my thinking correct, and/or could you point me towards a good resource that explains this kind of thing?

Interesting question! I'm not sure that I'm convinced your stabilizers define a unique quantum state, but since they appear to commute, they might define a unique measurement basis for a system with seven particles (i.e. they would stabilize $128=2^7$ distinct states.)

It sounds like you're taking the quotient of a subgroup $H$ of a product group $\mathbb G = \times^N G = G\times G\times ...$ ($N$ times) under a homomorphism from $(\times)^NG$ to $(\times)^{N'}G$ (where $N'<N$), and you might be asking if there is a sort of "quantum functor" for this, specifically involving the tensor product, density matrices, and the trace operation.  To start, let's suppose that the above homomorphism ignores components at index positions $i_B$ (so that $i_A$ denotes indices that are retained), and let's try to model the homomorphism through a group action of $\times^N G$ on $\otimes^N\mathcal H$, where $(g_1,g_2,\dots)\circ |\psi_1\rangle|\psi_2\rangle\cdots = |g_1\psi_1\rangle|g_2\psi_2\rangle\cdots$, and let's suppose that $H\leq \mathbb G$ denotes a complete set of pairwise commuting operators (i.e. a measurement basis) with eigenstates $|\psi_i\rangle$ (where $i$ is a multi-index.)
As I'm sure you're aware, in general the trace of $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ over a subsystem does not factor into another pure state.  Claim: when $\rho_{A,i}\equiv\text{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|_{AB})$ does factorize into $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|_A$ a particular measurement basis $H$, it is possible to factorize $|\psi\rangle_{AB}$ itself as $|\psi\rangle_A|\psi\rangle_B$.  From the above group action, and because the operators of interest belong to a subgroup $H\leq \times^NG$, it follows that for $h\in H$, $h|\psi\rangle_A|\psi\rangle_B = |h^{(A)}\psi\rangle_A|h^{(B)}\psi\rangle_B$ (i.e. the measurement operators preserve factorization.)  Consequently, if the $|\psi_i\rangle_{AB}$ $H$-eigenstates all factorize as $|\psi_i\rangle_A|\psi_i\rangle_B$, $|\psi_i\rangle_A$ and $|\psi_i\rangle_B$ must be eigenstates of $h^{(A)}$ and $h^{(B)}$ respectively.  Because the $h$ operators form a complete measurement basis, the $h^{(A)}$ operators (i.e. the image of $H$ under the above homomorphism) must resolve states in the $\otimes^{N'}\mathcal H$ space completely, and thus are also a complete measurement basis in the subsystem.
It is important to be aware that although the above correspondence was outlined on a formal level, caution must be exercised in trying to interpret its physical relevance.  From an implementation standpoint, the main problematic step is in isolating $h^{(A)}$ from $h^{(B)}$, which would require the discovery or implementation of an entirely new set of operators that address the $A$-subsystem exclusively: in general, the measured value of $h$ itself will depend on both the $A$ and $B$ subsystems, and its action on the $A$ subsystem will depend on components in the $B$ subsystem as well.
Note also that this is a very different problem from determining the actual stabilizer for a factorizable reduced state (i.e. a set of operators that uniquely specify $|\psi\rangle$ as a shared eigenmode.)
